# Did the apostles teach ideas about God the Father that were contrary to the teachings of first century Judaism?

Tags: nature-of-god, judaism, apostles

Early Christianity surely inherited theology from Judaism.  In particular, at least some of God's characteristics as taught by Judaism.  After all, Jesus and the apostles were Jews. Did they ever teach against the theology of Judaism at the time? In other words, are there parts of first-century Jewish theology they *didn't* inherit, and instead replaced with contrary beliefs?

The apostles wouldn't believe things that aren't from the Torah, nor things that were against the Torah, right? The Jews didn't teach polytheism, for example. Where can I find empirical evidence that shows they knew and understood the teachings of first century Judaism? It's useful to know if the teachings of the early church contradicted the nature of God according to the existing teachings of Judaism.

I'm looking for evidence that, aside perhaps from their beliefs about Jesus, the apostles weren't otherwise heretical in their beliefs about God, in the context of Judaism of that time (so, God is God as presented by the Torah).

Comment: This is a very vague question. In short, Christianity inherited the entirety of the Old Testament. Are you specifically asking about beliefs in addition to those from the OT?

Comment: Yeah, I know, too general.  I'll try to focus a bit.

Comment: I guess I should have asked a more direct question.

Comment: If you want help editing the question to get it within site guidelines, just say so. Could you elaborate a bit on what you're looking for? Do you want to know what teachings about God in the early church came from Judaism but not from the Old Testament?

Comment: Thanks.  Actually the reverse... and even in a negative sense.

The apostles wouldn't believe things that aren't from the Torah, nor things that were against the Torah, right?  The Jews didn't teach polytheism, for example.

Where can I find empirical evidence that shows they knew and understood these things?  

I think this isn't a completely daft question because any religion may try to incorporate Jesus into it, but it's useful to know if such a religion contradicts the nature of God according to what was perfectly clear to Jews back then.

Comment: There are some issues with that question. The biggest is that the Jews believed nothing that wasn't in the Torah. There were plenty of teachings and traditions built around the Torah that didn't carry over into Christianity. As far as teaching "against the Torah," the Pharisees and such at the time clearly saw them as doing such. What are you looking for evidence of?

Comment: I'm looking for evidence that, aside perhaps from their beliefs about Jesus, the apostles weren't otherwise heretical in their beliefs about God, in the context of Judaism of that time (so, God is God as presented by the Torah).

Comment: Alright, I've submitted a substantial edit that integrates those comments into your question.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess it was hard for me to articulate the question well!

Comment: I've further edited as it appears you are asking about the *apostles*, not the "early church" (which is typically understood to be the period following the apostles and ending around AD 500).

Comment: There is no evidence in Judaism that the Pharisees at the time were aware of any developing Christianity. They did not conclude it was teaching against or for Torah. That idea comes from Christian texts.

Comment: Well my question is practical, but I have to ask it in a generic way, and I'm having trouble translating it.  

I assume the apostles were more or less kosher Jews (excuse the pun), except for the incarnation etc. They had to defend their beliefs from the Jewish Bible.

Similarly, any religion that says it is in continuity with Judaism, and yet fundamentally does not agree with the characteristics of God laid out in the Torah, really needs to explain itself well.  And if it can't, then why should anyone give it any consideration at all?

Comment: Apart from the not so unimportant statement about God allegedly being the Father of a co-eternal, sentient being (a theoretically possible -but by no means obvious or necessary- interpretation of, say, Proverbs 8:22), they are not known to have otherwise diverged from the traditional Judaism of their day, insofar their doctrine of God is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

A great deal of early Christianity is anti-thematic to Judaism at that time.

In Judaism G'd is considered non-corporeal. So a son coming down, being human, dying (human trait), and rising, are all outside of Judaism at the time. Evidence of this belief in Judaism includes that Jews were called "atheists" by other groups of people at that time for their insistence that G'd doesn't have a body nor any worldly presentation.

In Judaism the existence of three G'd presentations, one being human, is borderline worship of idols (a human as a G'd). It's why belief in Jesus by a Jewish person, makes them an ex-patriot to Judaism. It put them outside Judaism and they'd have be make teshuva (repentance) to return.

In Judaism, sins are only the responsibility of the sinner, and can only be forgiven by the actions of the sinner to repent and change. There is no original sin taught in Judaism in any of the sacred or study texts (such as Talmud) which reflect beliefs from  the turn of the millennium. Since you aren't born with original sin, there is no need for saving from it.

In Judaism, the messiah will bring peace on earth and an end to all suffering. There is no 2nd coming concept. It's also not a particularly important concept in the 2 millennia since.  At the time, during the fight with the Roman's it was a hopeful idea being talked about. The messiah is supposed to come from the house of David, be a descendant of King David. Jesus is not. Others at the time were considered for the title, such as  Bar Kokhba who lead one of the most successful rebellions against the Romans, and was thought to be by Rabbi Akkiva. When it was unsuccessful, it was considered a mistaken idea. It's thought that Bar Kokhba met more of the criteria than Jesus.
https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/rabbi-akiva

A site with a lot of the basic concepts in Judaism is http://www.jewfaq.org. Reading through, one can see how concepts differ from Christianity.

---

There are also similarity in how G'd is taught. The idea of one g'd for all the world, being all powerful, was different than the beliefs of others around the Jews, and Christianity continued that belief.

Early Christianity borrows a lot from the pagans around it. However, it used that virtually rather than literally. For example, some local communities sacrificed live people to save their communities from sin. There is much debate how much of that borrowing is by the original apostles, and how much is from later interpretations.

Judaism had considerable elements that were intentionally the opposite of the communities around them. For instance, the belief that someone else can't die to save you from anything. With that, the idea in kosher laws around blood, are opposite to the drinking of blood to gain power that was used around them.

There are books written on the topic. I don't remember the names of ones I read parts of, but there are good sources on these concepts from early Christianity.

Comment: "In Judaism G'd is considered non-corporeal" You realize this is one of the *premises* of the Incarnation of God, right? How could they be opposed?

Comment: Jesus takes on human body. That is outside of Judaism's view of G'd as without human body (non-corporeal). I don't know what Incarnation of G'd states about Jesus having a body.

Comment: Those who believe in the Incarnation don't believe God has a body. That's the very point of an incarnation. There would be no incarnation if God had a body.

Comment: At some point during the incarnation process G'd takes on human form. That is opposite to the Jewish concept in non-corporeal that G'd doesn't take on human form. You need to address the human body of Jesus during this process, in order for us to discuss this, and so far haven't talked about. If he has a body and you believe it's not a body but he has a body form, that is opposite to Judaism's belief of non-corporeal. That's all there is to it. Believing it's not a body while it has body form, makes it outside Judaism's non-corporeal belief.

Comment: For God to take on a human form in the incarnation isn't God's nature transforming into a body ("God is man"), but God assuming a body for Himself, instead of for a mere mortal. God no more 'turns into' the body of Jesus any more than He turns into the the Temple building.Those prophets who saw God, saw some image God assumed, inasmuch as one cannot see God and live. When He does this in the incarnation, He doesn't become His temple or image, the humanity of Jesus: He assumes it as His own, for Himself, without turning into it. You'd need to ignore that in order to keep raising this objection.

Comment: You can parse this all you want in Christianity. The act of appearing to appear in human form violates Judaism's concept. I'm not debating. I'm telling the standard in Judaism, because that standard answered the original poster's question. You are raising objections to Judaism's concept of non-corporeal, but it is what it is.

Comment: I specifically avoided saying anything about whether Judaism is true or not. God being a man, and God becoming a man are separate things, that's all I wanted to inform you of as I perceived a false dichotomy between Judaism and the Incarnation in your answer which people should be aware of. The way you stated it was not 'God cannot take on a human form (something He does in the Torah anyway?) but that God is "incorporeal" which means God is not a man, which Christians agree with, and which is a different claim from 'God cannot in any way take on a corporeal nature in any sense.'

Comment: "God being a man, and God becoming a man are separate things" - both are  outside Judaism's view of non-corporeal. I referred to both. You then hyper focused on my generalized wording in my first reply to your "challenge" & ignored that I'd then made this point more clearly. You claim to avoid whether Judaism is true, then debate if Incarnation means Judaism's interpretation is wrong... with me who wasn't willing to debate the difference, only point it out.

........ Stack is telling me to avoid extended discussions in comments. If you wish to comment further, kindly take this to the "chat".

Comment: http://www.jewfaq.org/g-d.htm - In my answer, I referred to this website. This page explains more detail of Judaism's view of G'd and also why body is idolatry in Judaism's concept of G'd. Judaism isn't commenting on Christianity,  but the ideas of G'd do have some differences. ....... again, Stack wants this to go to chat. Please don't bring me into public discussion I don't see relevant to my answer... and bring this to chat if you want to discuss it.

Comment: Comments you don't find relevant aren't the only on-topic comments, and your reply to my first comment shows how you meant "in Judaism God is not corporeal," namely, that Christianity does. Nonetheless, you're right, this is not the place for discussion. God bless!

Comment: You had to get in one last attack at me & Judaism's view -- rather than take this to chat. You haven't even read the link I provided twice...... Religion isn't some black & white, non-corporeal means Christianity is corporeal. Your own link to a creative concept shows that even though it is STILL OUTSIDE JUDAISM'S view of G'd. Making black & white is poor arguing. I'd say G'd bless but you are purposely disrespectful to me & Judaism - rather than taking this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98517/discussion-between-curls-and-sola-gratia).

Comment: The Gospels present genealogies that show Jesus to be descended from David.

Comment: The question is genealogy of the mosiah with Judaism's methods (not in Christian interpretations). The question was whether there is a difference in Judaism & Christianity's views. Jesus doesn't qualify using Judaism's methods. .....I present these links, 1) not to argue whether Christianity believes Jesus is descendant, 2) nor to argue whether he is or isn't.... but to give Judaism's info that when used, concludes not. .... http://www.totheends.com/eligible.htm .... https://www.aish.com/jl/li/m/Who-is-the-Messiah.html .... https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/was-is-jesus-the-messiah